# How to make back/next buttons invisible while viewing the last and first fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-navigation

I am trying to create a multi page form using viewpager and fragments. The form needs to have bottom dots and "back"/"next" buttons to the right and left side of the dots, where the next button changes to "finish" on the last slide.

I managed to get the bottom dots and buttons to work. However I am lost at how to get the back button to not be visible when at the first fragment and the next button at the last.

My code:

MainActivity.java

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;

import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TabLayout tabLayout;
    ViewPager viewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
        viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPager);

        getTabs();
    }

    public void getTabs(){
       final ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
        viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(oneFragment.getInstance(),null); // this line can cause crashes
        viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(twoFragment.getInstance(),null); // this line can cause crashes
        viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(threeFragment.getInstance(),null); // this line can cause crashes

        viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
            }
        });
    }

    //Implement the listeners for the back and previous items
    public void goBack(View view) {
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(viewPager.getCurrentItem()-1);
    }
    public void goNext(View view) {
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(viewPager.getCurrentItem()+1);
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/back"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/back"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:onClick="goBack"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/next"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/next"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:onClick="goNext"/>

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_selector"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

ViewPagerAdapter.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;

public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private List<Fragment> fragmentList = new ArrayList<>(); // this line can cause crashes
    private List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(@NonNull FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return fragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fragmentList.size();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return stringList.get(position);
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title){
        fragmentList.add(fragment); // this line can cause crashes
        stringList.add(title);
    }
}
```

fragment example: oneFragment.java with layout row_one

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

public class OneFragment extends Fragment {

    public static OneFragment getInstance(){
        OneFragment oneFragment = new OneFragment();
        return oneFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(@NonNull Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_one, container,false);
        return view;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `addOnPageChangeListener` listenter to the ViewPager, and in `onPageSelected()` callback compare the selected/current `position` to the first (position = 0) or last position.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
    viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    final Button back = findViewById(R.id.back);
    final Button finish = findViewById(R.id.next);



    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {

            back.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            finish.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            
            if (position == 0) {
                back.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                PagerAdapter adapter = viewPager.getAdapter();
                if (adapter != null && position == adapter.getCount() - 1) {
                    finish.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });

    getTabs();
}
```

Also, the correct way to initialize a FragmentPagerAdapter is to return new Fragment instances from `getItem()`. You should ***never*** pass actual Fragment references to a FragmentPagerAdapter, and you should not keep them as a list.

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        if(position == 0) return new SampleFragment();
        if(position == 1) return new SampleFragment2();
        if(position == 2) return new SampleFragment3();
        throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected position " + position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        if(position == 0) return "Tab 1";
        if(position == 1) return "Tab 2";
        if(position == 2) return "Tab 3";
        throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected position " + position);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked. For anyone looking at this for examples I made the change of calling the getTabs()  at the end of onCreate rather than before adding the onChangeListener, which prevents the issue of the back button not disappearing upon launching the application.

Comment: It's better to `findViewById(...)` in `OnCreate`, not in `OnPageSelected` because `findViewById(...)` is not a cheap operation. So we prevent re-finding a view every page-selected event

Comment: @zihadrizkyef valuable note, modified now

Comment: @MKer updated the answer with your suggestion .. please accept the answer by marking the tick mark